# grunt-contrib-sass: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and CP850

Tags: character-encoding, sass, gruntjs

While trying to use grunt to convert my sass files into normal css files i get the warning:

```
Warning: Encoding::CompabilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and CP850.
```

However when I run sass calling the file(s) everything works as it should even though no encoding is specified by me. My `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```
[...]
sass: {
    main: {
        files: {
            'css/theme/default.css': 'css/theme/source/default.scss',
                'css/theme/beige.css': 'css/theme/source/beige.scss',
            'css/theme/night.css': 'css/theme/source/night.scss',
            'css/theme/serif.css': 'css/theme/source/serif.scss',
            'css/theme/simple.css': 'css/theme/source/simple.scss',
            'css/theme/sky.css': 'css/theme/source/sky.scss',
            'css/theme/moon.css': 'css/theme/source/moon.scss',
            'css/theme/solarized.css': 'css/theme/source/solarized.scss',
            }
        }
    }
[...]
```

which is a part of the [`Gruntfile.js`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) I forked from the reveal.js on GitHub. I took a look at the [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) on GitHub and tried to find the option to change the encoding manualy. However it apears that there is none (maybe I just overlooked it?).
I think a keypart of the problem is that I am using Windows 8 and not any Unix based OS.

So my question is:
How do i get rid of this warning? Or how do i fix the code to work properly?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I just found out that get the same error when running `sass --watch input.scss:output.css` while I don't get the error using `sass input.scss:output.css` so the problem might only be a sass related thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this error when trying to use the command:

```
sass --watch global.scss:global.css --style compressed
```

And the cause was the most stupid cause ever... I had this folder: **E:\Dropbox[Websites][External] Fundación Global\css** and I run the command in there, and SASS returned this same error: *Warning: Encoding::CompabilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and CP850.*

I just needed to take out the **ó** from the folder's path!

That simple and silly! Just changed this: **...Fundación Global\css** for this **...Fundacion Global\css** and I have SASS watching with no issues again.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. I had the same thing, and could not get my head around it. Finally solved it!